# How to extract the structure of relationships amongst variables in a system of equations?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, expression-manipulation

*Mathematica* being a CAS, I would have thought what I'm trying to do a natural task. But I have not been able to find any information on this in the Internet.

Basically, I have a large collection of equations that describe relationships between a large set of variables. Can I use the symbol manipulation functions of *Mathematica* to extract this structure and plot the results as a directed network graph?

For example,

```
Y = a + b X
Z = 1/X + Y
```

would give a graph that has the following edges:

```
a -> Y
b -> Y
X -> Y
X -> Z
Y -> Z
```

Comment: Can you give a small example illustrating what you're expecting to get?

Comment: To avoid having to make multiple future updates to any answers, can you set down the form of your equations precisely (e.g. does the LHS always have a single variable? are the equations always polynomial in form?) and give an example *in valid Mathematica syntax* that is representative of all your actual systems?  Please use code blocks to format the Mathematica code you post.

Comment: Generally, the procedure is to separate RHS from LHS (see [Everything is an Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html) for a starting point; this is an easy task once you know the basics of Mathematica), then extract variables (`Variables` for polynomial, or non-Head non-`NumericQ` symbols extracted with `Cases` otherwise) and build the graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it was mentioned in the question and in the comments this is fairly easy to program.

```
eqs = {Y == a + b X, Z == 1/X + Y};

edges = Flatten@
  Map[Outer[Rule, 
     Cases[{#[[2]]}, s_Symbol /; Not@NumericQ[s], \[Infinity]], 
     Cases[{#[[1]]}, s_Symbol /; Not@NumericQ[s], \[Infinity]]] &, 
   eqs]

(* {a -> Y, b -> Y, X -> Y, X -> Z, Y -> Z} *)
```

The code above assumes that the equations are properly defined. Let us plot the graph with the obtained edges:

```
Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

A more complicated example for plotting dependencies between symbols can be found in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109942/34008) of the question [What's the analogue of UML in Mathematica land?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18535/whats-the-analogue-of-uml-in-mathematica-land).

Comment: `s_Symbol /; Not@NumericQ[s]` is better because it excludes the likes of `Pi`.  `Cases` already has `Heads -> False` so that part is fine.

Comment: @Szabolcs Good point! I was going for simplicity of the code, and did not consider that case.

Comment: Using undocumented functionality: ``Flatten[Outer[Rule, Reduce`FreeVariables[#2], Reduce`FreeVariables[#1]] & @@@ {Y == a + b X, Z == 1/X + Y}]``

Comment: @J.M. Thanks! I did not know about ``Reduce`FreeVariables``.

Answer (score 6):

```
eqsToGraph = Block[{Equal = Rule @@@ Tuples[{Variables@#2, Variables@#1}] &}, 
    Graph[Join @@ #, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]] &;
```

Example:

```
eqsToGraph@{Y == a + b X, Z == 1/X + Y}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eqsToGraph@{Y == a + b X, Z + W == 1/X + Y}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What if the LHS is a more complicated expression, e.g. `Y + Z == a + b X`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov, good point. Updated with a fix.

Comment: Your answer is a very good approach!